# Spring Boot Admin in Kubernetes cannot probe custom actuator urls

Tags: kubernetes, spring-boot-admin

I had been following your blog and came across your article on boot admin with Kubernetes. I am stuck with one issue - I am not sure if I am missing something, but here is my problem -

I am building an admin-service boot application that discovers service in the cluster it is deployed.

And now, I have several other applications running in the same cluster, let's just say same name space.

So far,

admin-service (boot app)

customer-service (boot app - server port 8501 and management port 8502)

application-b (boot app - server port 8901 and management port 8902)

..

..

So, my admin-service is able to identify these applications and their pods, but its by default looking at default actuator url for health and any other information.

Which is failing. Is there a workaround to configure these based on applications? Any suggestions?

My actual requirement - Have a single portal where I can update log level runtime on my application, customer-service in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: can you please share specs from your yaml file.

Comment: I suggest using https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-kubernetes